# I'm not getting correct data (usually first 16 bytes) when using evp_sealinit/ evp_openinit api. what am i doing wrong here?

Tags: openssl, rsa, public-key

What am I doing wrong here? I must be missing something..

I'm using the EVP_Seal/ EVP_Open API. I've generated the public/private key and the certificate. I'm seeing some wierd things - the first 16bytes  that I'm getting back after decoding are garbage. If my data is small (smaller that 16 bytes), then I'm not getting any output from the EVP_Open functions.

Heres my test program:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <string.h>

    #include <openssl/ssl.h>
    #include <openssl/err.h>
    #include <openssl/rsa.h>
    #include <openssl/pem.h>
    #include <openssl/err.h>
    #include <openssl/rand.h>

    #define PORT 6999
    #define HOST "localhost"

    #define PUBLIC_KEYFILE "pubkey.pem"
    #define CERT_FILE "server.crt"

    #define PRIVATE_KEYFILE "server.key"

    void run_client(void);

    EVP_CIPHER_CTX en_ctx;
    EVP_CIPHER_CTX de_ctx;

    typedef struct {
    int keylen;
    unsigned char key[512];
    unsigned char iv[EVP_MAX_IV_LENGTH];
     } keys_t;

     unsigned char msg[1024];
     unsigned char enc_buf[1024];
     unsigned char de_buf[1024];


     int main(int argc, char **argv)
     {

     // Init malloc, free etc for OpenSSL's CRYPTO_malloc_init();
     ERR_load_BIO_strings();    
     OpenSSL_add_all_algorithms();
     run_client();

     return 0;  

     }

     int encrypt_with_cert(unsigned char **secret_key, int *keylen, 
                           unsigned char **out_iv, 
                   unsigned char *data, int *datalen)
    {
    FILE *fp;
    X509 *x509;
    EVP_PKEY *pkey;

        unsigned char *ek;
        int eklen;
    int retval = 0;
    unsigned char iv[EVP_MAX_IV_LENGTH];
    int i=0;

        RAND_pseudo_bytes(iv, EVP_MAX_IV_LENGTH);

        fp = fopen(CERT_FILE, "r");
    if (!fp) {
      fprintf(stderr, "Cannot open certificate file\n");
      goto out;
    }

    x509 = PEM_read_X509(fp, NULL, 0, NULL);
    if (x509 == NULL) {
      ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
      goto out;
    }
    fclose(fp);

    pkey = X509_extract_key(x509);

    X509_free(x509);

    if (pkey == NULL) {
      ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
    }

    EVP_CIPHER_CTX_init(&en_ctx);
    ek = malloc(EVP_PKEY_size(pkey));

    if (!EVP_SealInit(&en_ctx, EVP_aes_256_cbc(), &ek, 
                          &eklen, iv, &pkey, 1)) {
      fprintf(stderr, "EVP_SealInit failed\n");
      retval = 3;
      goto out_free;
    }

     int buf_len = 0;
     int tot_len = 0;

     printf("Encoding string: {%s}, len: %d\n", data, *datalen);
     memset(enc_buf, 0 , 1024);

     EVP_SealInit(&en_ctx, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 1);
     EVP_SealUpdate(&en_ctx, enc_buf, &buf_len, data, *datalen);
     tot_len += buf_len;

     EVP_SealFinal(&en_ctx, enc_buf+buf_len, &buf_len);
     tot_len += buf_len;

     *(enc_buf + tot_len) = '\0';
     *datalen = tot_len;

     printf("Encoded length: %d\n", tot_len);
     printf("Encoded message: {");
     for (i=0; i< tot_len; i++) {
    printf("%02x", enc_buf[i]);
     }
     printf("}\n");

     goto out;

      out_free:
     EVP_PKEY_free(pkey);
     free(ek);

      out:
    *secret_key = ek;
    *keylen = eklen;
    *out_iv = iv;
    return retval;
    }

    void decrypt_message(unsigned char *secret_key, int keylen, 
                         unsigned char *iv, int buflen)
    {
    FILE *privkey;

    int retval = 0;
    int klen=0;

    int tot_len = 0;
    EVP_PKEY *pkey;
    int i = 0;

    privkey = fopen(PRIVATE_KEYFILE, "r");
    if (!privkey) {
      fprintf(stderr, "Error opening private key\n");
        }   

    pkey = PEM_read_PrivateKey(privkey, NULL, 0 , NULL);
    if (!pkey) {
      fprintf(stderr, "Error loading Server's RSA private key\n");
      retval = 2;
      goto out; 
    }


    if(keylen != EVP_PKEY_size(pkey)) {
       EVP_PKEY_free(pkey);
       fprintf(stderr, "keylength mismatch!\n");
       retval = 2;
       goto out;
    }       

    klen = EVP_OpenInit(&de_ctx, EVP_aes_256_cbc(), secret_key, keylen, iv, pkey);
    if (klen == 0) {
      fprintf(stderr, "EVP_OpenInit failed\n");
    }

    int de_len = 0;
    tot_len = 0;

    printf("\n\nNow decoding..\n");
    printf("Encoded length: %d\n", buflen);
    printf("Encoded message: {");
    for (i=0; i< buflen; i++) {
      printf("%02x", enc_buf[i]);
    }
    printf("}\n");


    EVP_OpenInit(&de_ctx, NULL, NULL, keylen, NULL, NULL);
    EVP_OpenUpdate(&de_ctx, de_buf, &de_len, enc_buf, buflen);
    tot_len += de_len;


    EVP_OpenFinal(&de_ctx, de_buf+tot_len, &de_len);
    tot_len += de_len;
    *(de_buf+tot_len) = '\0';


    printf("Decoded length: %d,  String: %s\n", tot_len, de_buf);

     out:
    fclose(privkey);
return;
    } 

   void run_client()
   {

    unsigned char *secret_key = NULL;
    int keylen;
    unsigned char *iv = NULL;
    int data_len = 0;
    int retval = 0;

    //strcpy((char *)msg, "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789");
    //strcpy((char *)msg, "this is a secret message\n");


        strcpy((char *)msg, "1234567890");

        data_len = strlen((char *)msg) + 1; 

    retval = encrypt_with_cert(&secret_key, &keylen, &iv, msg, &data_len);
    if (retval != 0) {
    printf("encrypt with certificate failed! retval = %d\n", retval);
    }

    decrypt_message(secret_key, keylen, iv, data_len);

    }
```

When I run this here's what I get:
        [sample]$ gcc -Wall -g -o openssl_seal -lcrypto openssl_seal.c

```
    [sample]$ ./openssl_seal
    Encoding string: {1234567890}, len: 11
    Encoded length: 16
    Encoded message: {9753c483d6816b64693f604b2376f0a0}


    Now decoding..
    Encoded length: 16
    Encoded message: {9753c483d6816b64693f604b2376f0a0}
    Decoded length: 0,  String:


   [sample]$ gcc -Wall -g -o openssl_seal -lcrypto openssl_seal.c
   [sample]$ ./openssl_seal
   Encoding string: {abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789}, len: 37
   Encoded length: 48
   Encoded message:          {ad264f30fe70cc6f9c8d712073bc72049e7f7515a28c1cf0aeef648d6c4c4bfd717ae2fd21396bb95eb7ec0ce88f7f9d}


   Now decoding..
   Encoded length: 48
   Encoded message: {ad264f30fe70cc6f9c8d712073bc72049e7f7515a28c1cf0aeef648d6c4c4bfd717ae2fd21396bb95eb7ec0ce88f7f9d}
   Decoded length: 37,  String: abcd.VO[vтOqrstuvwxyz0123456789
```

Comment: You never initialized your decryption context, `de_ctx`. It is value-declared local-automatic, and fed straight to `EVP_OpenInit` by address with no initialization. This is one of the reasons I *never* use value-declared contexts with `EVP_CIPHER_CTX_init` and instead opt for dynamic contexts (`EVP_CIPHER_CTX_new`). It's simply too easy to forget, and worse, it can appear to work correctly sometimes, and not others.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are calling `EVP_SealInit` twice, and ignoring the iv parameter the second time. You should only call this method once, saving the IV parameter and transmitting it to the decryption side. Similarly you should only call `EVP_OpenInit` once.

Comment: No, that doesnt work either. I tried removing the second call, but get the same results. According to the man page, its ok to call those funcctions twice as long as the type is set to NULL. It will just ignore all the NULL values and overwrite the non-NULL values for the context.

Comment: FYI, the OP never initialized the decryption context, `de_ctx`. It is value-declared, and fed straight to `EVP_OpenInit` by address with no initialization. This is one of the reasons I *never* use value-declared contexts with `EVP_CIPHER_CTX_init` and instead opt for dynamic contexts (`EVP_CIPHER_CTX_new`). It's simply too easy to forget, and worse, it can appear to work correctly sometimes, and not others due to undefined behavior.